# How to handle a big amount of whitelabel sites (with multi-site)

Tags: localization, multi-site

For one of our clients we need to setup a whitelabel template. 
I was considering doing this with Craft's Multi site feature which works fine in that way Content management wise.

But, it's probably going to be 50+ whitelabel sites (multi sites) but, I'm afraid this is going to be a mess in the CMS.

Is there another way to handle this issue or, is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Craft just isn't set up to handle this many sites, as you said it will likely be a hot mess. One way to circumvent could be to create your own plugin to manage things.

Either way I would get in touch with P+T as depending on your use (if every site is a new client) this may be outside of the license agreement.

Comment: Well it's not like a "new" client. The site sells courses & exams. Other company's which require those courses. They can buy a package so they get their own name / logo & color scheme on the website when a user connected to that company is logged in instead of showing my clients theme / logo.

Comment: In that case could you get away with yourdomain.com/companyname as a url? If so you could just create a channel with all the companies, then depending on the url it will style according to that companies details.

Comment: I'm considering a approach like that yes. URL's will be whitelabel.domain.com though

Comment: I would post another question asking this in particular as I'm convinced it's doable. I imagine it would involve putting the craft index.php on the subdomain, then possibly setting in config/general.php that sets a variable to the subdomain.

Comment: Well it's not that I don't know how to handle this. Was more looking for a good solution on managing 50+ multi-sites from a Content Manager's perspective

Comment: I don't doubt it. The answer was that was going to be hard, so I suggested using a channel? But looks like you're still looking at using multi-site.